# Which sentence would be best for situation below?

Tags: sentence-usage

Teacher told me and my friend  to read  some books? But my friend would two more books which are Tom Sawyer and Robinson Crusoe than me. In this case If I say the sentences below would these be grammatically correct ? Those may not ve natural but as told I wonder If these are grarmmatically correct?

> In addition to the books I will read , he will read Tom Sawyer and Robinson Crusoe.
>
> As an extra to the books I will read, he will read Tom Sawyer and Robinson Crusoe.
>
> As more than the books I will read, he will read Tom Sawyer and Robinson Crusoe.

I wonder if especially the third sentence is correct or not .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the sentences are grammatically correct: the first two mean what you intended, though I prefer the first version. The third doesn't make sense. To understand why, let's turn those three sentences around:

> He will read Tom Sawyer and Robinson Crusoe in addition to the books I will read.
>
> He will read Tom Sawyer and Robinson Crusoe as an extra to the books I will read
>
> He will read Tom Sawyer and Robinson Crusoe as more than the books I will read.

In the second and third sentence, **[as](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/as)** is a preposition and is **used to describe the purpose or quality of someone or something**.

**as an extra ...** nicely because these two books are an extra, in addition to the books that you will read.

**as more than...** suggests that these two books *on their own* are more than the number of books you read in total.

Comment: Would it be correc if I say only “ as more than me” like “As more than me , he will read Tom Sawyer and Robinson Crusoe.”

Comment: No, that would not be correct.